# Finding strings between two strings in lua

Tags: lua

I have been trying to find all possible strings in between 2 strings

This is my input: `"print/// to be able to put any amount of strings here   endprint///"`

The goal is to print every string in between `print///` and `endprint///`

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to get, because you use the word "string" wrongly. "String" - is the whole text. "substring" - is the part of the string. If you want to get the text between ```print``` and ```endprint``` - you want to get a substring. But if you want "many" of them, I guess you are interested in the space-separated words. Please clarify what exactly you want to get in your example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Lua's string patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) to achieve that.

```
local text = "print/// to be able to put any amount of strings here   endprint///"

print(text:match("print///(.*)endprint///"))
```

The pattern `"print///(.*)endprint///"` captures any character that is between `"print///"` and `"endprint///"`

Answer (score 0):

[Lua string patterns here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1)

In this kind of problem, you don't use the greedy quantifiers `*` or `+`, instead, you use the lazy quantifier `-`. This is because `*` matches until the last occurrence of the sub-pattern after it, while `-` matches until the first occurence of the sub-pattern after it. So, you should use this pattern:

> print///(.-)endprint///

And to match it in Lua, you do this:

```lua
local text = "print/// to be able to put any amount of strings here   endprint///"

local match = text:match("print///(.-)endprint///")
-- `match` should now be the text in-between.
print(match) -- "to be able to put any amount of strings here   "
```